# Scrapy save html element to html file

Tags: python, scrapy, scapy

I want to save div element class="col-md-12 blog-data" (contains images)  to html file.   Where should I put response.css ? I'm new to python and scrapy .

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'mysite.com/articles/1',            
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):         
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:

     f.write(response.body) //I've used it here and it gave me blank html

    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Is it possible to concat custom string like this and save to html file?Please Give me some examples. Thank you.

```
mytext="<html><head></head><body>
<div id='mycustomelement'>
{  ('.blog-data')response //how to get this  }
</div></body></html>"
```

Comment: your code looks fine. Are you getting something in `response.body`?? And also you can also concat string and save html file.

Comment: @PrakashPalnati Yes  But when I change response.body to respond.css('.blog-data') There is no output.I don't know where should I put this selector.

Comment: no you cannot do `respond.css`. If  want to concat a css to a div, you gotta use regex and concat

Comment: @PrakashPalnati I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use `response.css` to give styling. `response` object will not have a method called `.css`. f want to concat a css to a div, you gotta use regex and concat Or a cleaner approach would be just append mystyle.css file in the head, And write down all your styles in mystle.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

you can do this using BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)

metatag = soup.new_tag('link')
metatag.attrs['rel'] = 'stylesheet'
metatag.attrs['type'] = 'text/css'
metatag.attrs['src'] = 'mystyle.css'

soup.head.append(metatag)
```

Comment: Can you give me an example to of how to use class selector to get data and write to html file?I've been searching for several days.The tutorial only show me how to write whole web page to html file.

Comment: what data you want to get by using class selector?? a text ??

Comment: Texts and images. I have to move 15gb blog contents from normal php website (which is impossible to export using sql) to wordpress.Wordpress has plugin html importer.So what I want to achieve is clean html with blog  content.

Comment: yes you can.. you can use same `BeautifulSoup` module to parse html content and get the data. in your case, it is `src` I suppose

Comment: Thank you so much.Now I know where should I start.